# How to pass material row template to custom table

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I have created my custom table using angular material.

[this](https://github.com/yantrab/swagular/blob/master/projects/swagular/components/src/table/table.component.html) is the source code.

I try to add an option to pass custom row template so I will be sent it like that:

```html
<my-table [dataSource]="data">
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</my-table>
```

So i added `@ContentChildren(MatRowDef) row: MatRowDef<any>;` to my table component, and trying to use it in the template:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="row; else defaultRowTemplate" [ngTemplateOutlet]="row.template">
</ng-container> 
<ng-template #defaultRowTemplate>
  <tr  mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
</ng-template>
```

but it is not working, there is some way to do it correctly?

[link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dpd6lf?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.html) to stackblitz.

Comment: trying to achieve this now. Were you able to find a solution @yantrab?